# django - no reverse match for login view

Tags: django

I am just trying out django and following the documentation for authentication.

Basically I want to take a look at the user login form page, but I am getting:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.login'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

My settings.py (INSTALLED_APPS)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

---

EDIT: I realized I was looking at the wrong thing. The error occurs in the template file:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Specifically for the line:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

Comment: Side note: this worked for me in the view: `reverse('login')`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
url(r'^accounts/login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

And after your edit:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
```

**EDIT**
in `settings.py` file of django, this line:

`APPEND_SLASH = False`

tells whether your reverse url finish with slash or not. Then

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
url(r'^accounts/login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

should work as well.

Comment: This statement is incorrect : `There should not be single quotation around...` according to the latest Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url . The right answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631551/781695

Answer (score 38):

Try set name for url and use it in url tag:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
```

and in template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Comment: This one is right i think. The other answers keep suggesting to reference the python package path instead of the name in the post url of the template

Comment: It worked for me aswell. Note that in the asdf_enel_hak answer the url regular expression does not end with metacharacter $ , so might be a security issue??

Comment: +1 - Good use of named url patterns to avoid ambiguity. Even better would be to use `action="{% url 'myapp:login' %}"`

Comment: Note that in 1.5 and later, `url` requires a string, so you'll need quotes, i.e. `{% url 'login' %}`

Answer (score 5):

Try adding name='login' as a keyword inthe url

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
```

and then calling reverse('login').

Comment: still get the same error when trying to access localhost/accounts/login

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion a better **urls.py** file (to be clean and still very explicit), also updated for Django 1.10 would be:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login')
]
```

And in the template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Note that `url` now requires a string so the `'login'` in the template must be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with namespacing your apps urls in the project/urls.py file. 
One solution is to remove the namespace and write out each url explicitly but for this particular problem...

This should work :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url '<namespace_name>:django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```